# Covering the unit sphere with sparse vectors

Tags: references, sparse, high-dimensional, probability-inequalities, geometry

I'm looking for references for covering the $d$-dimensional unit sphere

$$
\mathbb{S}^{d - 1} = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \| x \| = 1 \right\}
$$

I'm trying to cover $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ with vectors with $k$ nonzero coefficients (ideally at most some multiple of $\log d$ or even $\sqrt{d}$).  In other words, i'm looking for a set $\mathcal{N}$ such that $\bar{x} \in \mathcal{N} \Rightarrow \| \bar{x} \|_0 \leq k$, and

$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}, \; \exists \bar{x} \in \mathcal{N} :
\| x - \bar{x} \| \leq \varepsilon
$$
for some small constant $\varepsilon > 0$. Hence:

> **Question**: What is the minimum number of $k$-sparse vectors required to cover $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ with distance at most $\varepsilon$?

**Edit**: I'm not even sure a covering with sparse vectors that has logarithmic or square-root dependence on $d$ exists. If it exists, then its minimum cardinality definitely has to be exponential in $d$, since we know (e.g. from Corollary 4.2.13 in [1]) that any $\varepsilon$-net of the unit sphere has covering number at least $\left( \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \right)^d$.

[1]: *Roman Vershynin. High Dimensional Probability with Applications in Data Science, [draft ed.](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought, I think we can conclude that finding such a cover is impossible. Consider the vector of all $1$'s with appropriate scaling:

$$
v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \left(1 \; \dots \; 1\right)^\top \in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}
$$

and consider a $k$-sparse vector $\bar{v}$. Then

$$
\#\{i: (v - \bar{v})_i \neq 0\} \geq d - k
$$
so the approximation error will satisfy

$$
\|v - \bar{v}\|_2 \geq 
\sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^{d - k} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \right)^2 }
= \sqrt{\frac{d - k}{d}} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{k}{d}}
$$

It is obvious that for this error to be independent of $d$ we would have to make sure that $k \sim c d$, otherwise for a large enough $d$ this approximation error could be driven arbitrarily close to $1$.